# find all functions in a package that use a function

Tags: r

I would like to find all functions in a package that use a function. By functionB "using" functionA I mean that there exists a set of parameters such that functionA is called when functionB is given those parameters.

Also, it would be nice to be able to control the level at which the results are reported. For example, if I have the following:

```
outer_fn <- function(a,b,c) {
    inner_fn <- function(a,b) {
        my_arg <- function(a) {
            a^2
        }
        my_arg(a)
    }
    inner_fn(a,b)
}
```

I might or might not care to have `inner_fn` reported. Probably in most cases not, but I think this might be difficult to do.

Can someone give me some direction on this?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.sigmafield.org/2010/09/21/r-function-of-the-day-foodweb

Comment: Nice, thanks! Should I delete/close this post?

Comment: If Ben posts this as an answer, you can accept this answer (and he gets points :)). And you should definitely not close the post. SO also acts as a repository for information seekers.

Comment: @Paul thanks for the advice. I thought that since he posted as a comment that this must have been a repeated question. But maybe he didn't want to answer because his answer was just a reference? Ok I'll leave it.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe he thought the answer was so short that it did not warrant a full answer.

Comment: I generally start by posting *very* brief answers -- ones that are just an idea that I haven't checked, or just links to further information -- as comments, if I don't have time to elaborate further. That way someone else can pick them up and incorporate them in an answer if I don't get to it.  I don't know if that is how one is supposed to do things on SO, but it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @BenBolker That sounds like a very sensible approach.

Answer (score 3):

A small step to find uses of functions is to find where the function name is used. Here's a small example of how to do that:

```
findRefs <- function(pkg, fn) {
  ns <- getNamespace(pkg)
  found <- vapply(ls(ns, all.names=TRUE), function(n) {
     f <- get(n, ns)
     is.function(f) && fn %in% all.names(body(f))
  }, logical(1))

  names(found[found])
}

findRefs('stats', 'lm.fit')
#[1] "add1.lm"  "aov"      "drop1.lm" "lm"       "promax"
```

...To go further you'd need to analyze the body to ensure it is a function call or the FUN argument to an `apply`-like function or the f argument to `Map` etc...  - so in the general case, it is nearly impossible to find all legal references...

Then you should really also check that getting the name from that function's environment returns the same function you are looking for (it might use a different function with the same name)... This would actually handle your "inner function" case.

Comment: thanks, this seems useful for a custom function if I ever want to fine-tune things.

Answer (score 3):

(Upgraded from a comment.) There is a very nice `foodweb` function in Mark Bravington's [mvbutils](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvbutils/index.html) package with a lot of this capability, including graphical representations of the resulting call graphs. [This blog post](http://sigmafield.org/2010/09/21/r-function-of-the-day-foodweb) gives a brief description.