# How to find function causing package dependency

Tags: r

Having installed some package (A) dependent on other (B), how can one find the functions of (A) causing dependecies on (B)?

I want to find out why is one package dependent on the other. Usually it is because the code of dependant wants to use some functions from already existing other package. Therefore the author of package sets the dependency. I am searching the way how to localize such a functions within the dependant.

Comment: Probably more than you're looking for, but the answer is likely somewhere in here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/visualizing-the-cran-graphing-package-dependencies/ For a single package, the list is on it's CRAN page.

Comment: I think you need to add more details.  This is vague.

Comment: So package A uses package B and you want to know where/why? I guess you could use a text-processing tool (probably not R itself) to search A's code for B's function names...

Comment: Yes, that is the DIY way, which I of course consider, but first I am trying if there is anything ready.

Comment: How do you know A is dependent on B?  Does the DESCRIPTION file of A say "Depends: B"?  Does it say "Imports: B"?  Does the NAMESPACE file tell exactly which functions are imported?

Comment: In my case the DESCRIPTION file of A say "Depends: B" and namespace uses wildmarks.

Comment: You could remove "B" from Depends and run R CMD check.  You'll see bunch of  NOTES telling you there is "no visible global function definition for [a function from B]"

Comment: Perhaps you could put together a solution using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174695/find-all-functions-in-a-package-that-use-a-function?rq=1 ...

Comment: R CMD check way seems to me good, I will try to find out what is check doing and then use its method. Thanks.